# After trying various imports, I still get the error: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, import

*This question has been asked before, but I have tried the solutions that others have gotten and they do not work for me. I list the solutions I have tried at the bottom of this question.*

After trying multiple import variations in my ionic2 application, I still get the error,

```
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.
```

when trying to use the `map` function from rxjs. The following is my code.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the LevelTestDataProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class LevelTestDataProvider {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello LevelTestDataProvider Provider');
  }

  getRemoteData() {

    this.http.get('PUT JSON URL HERE').map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    })

  }

}
```

I have tried the following import statements:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

---

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'; // causes an error
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

---

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

---

```
import { map } from "rxjs/operators"; // causes an error
```

---

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

---

Additionally, I have made sure my Typescript version is up-to-date. It is currently version 2.6.2. I double-checked that my `package.json` file reflects this version.

**UPDATE 1:** My RxJS version is 5.5.2

Comment: what's your RxJS version?

Comment: My RxJS version is 5.5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from version v5, we are supposed to use

> [Pipeable Operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md)

Furthermore, `res.json()` will not work in Angular's new [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http). The `res` is already a parsed json object.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

this.http.get('PUT JSON URL HERE')
.pipe(map((res: Response) => {
    return res.json(); // will not work using HttpClient
    return res;
))
.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This is very great. I still have one small issue though. When I run `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';` as you have above, I get `'rxjs/operators'` underlined with the error: `File '/xxx/xxx/xxx/node_modules/rxjs/operators/index.d.ts' is not a module.` Do you know the cause of this?

Comment: I would try deleting node_modules and package-lock.json doing an npm install again.

Comment: I restarted my text editor and it fixed the problem! Thank you for your help and additional pointers.